# What rules govern nomination of an animated film for Academy Award for Best Picture?

Tags: animation, academy-awards

In the history of Academy awards only three animated movies were nominated for Best Picture.

1. [Beauty and the Beast](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101414/?ref_=ttawd_awd_tt) (1991)
2. [Up](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1049413/?ref_=ttawd_awd_tt) (2009)
3. [Toy Story 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0435761/?ref_=ttawd_awd_tt) (2010)

Out of these three Up and Toy Story 3 were also nominated for and won the award for Best Animated Feature Film of the Year. Beauty and the Beast wasn't nominated for the same because, well, that award didn't exist back then in 1991.

**Questions:**

1. Are there any special criteria for an animated film to be included in the nominations for Best Picture award?
2. Why do they include an animated film in the Best Picture nominations list (and the respective voting process) when there is already a separate category for Best Animated Feature.

I have gone through respective Wikipedia and news articles but didn't find any information on it. I also checked the official [rules](http://www.oscars.org/sites/oscars/files/89aa_rules.pdf). But these rules talk about mostly about the technicalities the voting and submission process etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any special criteria for an animated film to be included in the nominations for Best Picture award?

### Essentially, there are NO special differences that apply.

Any film that *meets the criteria* for **Best Picture** can be nominated as such if it is decided to do so.

Obviously, there is a separate **Best Animated Feature** that has its own criteria but these are not mutually exclusive like *Best Actor/Best Supporting Actor* are.

In fact, it is specifically stated in the [**rules**](http://www.oscars.org/sites/oscars/files/89aa_rules.pdf) that:

> Films submitted in the Animated Feature Film category may qualify for Academy Awards in other categories, **including Best Picture, provided they comply with the rules governing those categories.**

---

> Why do they include an animated film in the Best Picture nominations list (and the respective voting process) when there is already a separate category for Best Animated Feature.

Because they aren't judged on the *same criteria*.

A **Best Picture** is actually a broad canvas but the **Best Animated Feature** is a different beast entirely and should be judged on those *specific* merits and be noted accordingly.